# php codeigniter slow initial load

Tags: php, performance, apache, codeigniter, debugging

There is a site. Everything was just ok, but suddenly its working a bit strange:
http://gtmetrix.com/reports/bienestarenelhogar.com/bSruWlXF (click the timeline)

It's usual apache+php+mysql

The initial request takes 15 seconds. Its using codeigniter 2.1.0. I have suspicion that the igniter is causing the problem, since the other php pages are just ok.

I currently try to get to logs, but I don't have root and can't sudo on the server. Any other way to diagnose that?

(I'm not a php guy, I'm all about java)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I dont think this is a problem with CI (meaning CI's system files), but more of how you constructed your code. Does this happen on your local machine as well?

Comment: To debug the view, i would try to temporarily remove certain parts of the code, like the Chat plugin you have, or whatever is creating your iframes. Remove each section of code and test it out, this should tell you if the problem lies in your view's code.

Answer (score 0):

by enabling caching in your codeigniter app, you can boost up your app, much better. just need to append some code in project's `.htaccess` file.

```
ExpiresActive On

<Directory "/path/to/public_html/files">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ExpiresDefault A300
    <FilesMatch "\.html$">
        Expires A86400
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png|js|css)$">
        Expires A2592000
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try. Though its interesting why this degradation actually happened.

Comment: I think by default CodeIgniter Dont allow to cache normally, CI gives functionality to generate caching https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html , Once I had same issue and then used Above code in `.htaccess`, and it solved the problem.